# Проблема с интерфейсом Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, интерфейс

Проблема не с кодом `Interfase`, а с самим интерфейсом редактора.
То ли я забыл, как он выглядел и так должно быть, то ли что-то реально не так.
Мне кажется, классы раньше выделялись цветом, или их методы выделялись, но я помню, что не было такой монотонности цвета. Что скажите?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот полный скрин студии:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вы раньше пользовались кастомными цветовыми настройками или решарпером, который может перекрашивать код другими цветами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня случилась похожая ситуация в 2019 студии после обновления на версию 16.5.x (точную версию не помню), некоторые цвета действительно пропали, перенастроил вручную.

**Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Fonts and Colors**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто перенастройте под себя заново **User Members**.